# Find and replace from given word to right parenthesis

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have just taken up the VBA route to automate a few day today tasks so pls excuse if I sound very naive
I'm trying to open a word document & then searching for a expression to highlight(Bold) it,however Im getting error "User defined type not defined"
I'm able to open the word document but unable to perform the pattern search.I have gathered bits & peices of code from internet, however its not working
I'm using Office 2013 & have added the Microsoft VBscript Reg Ex 5.5 in references.
The pattern Im searching is starting from "Dear" till ) is encountered.
Cheers #GoingMad#

```
Sub Pattern_Replace()

Dim regEx, Match, Matches
Dim rngRange As Range

Dim pathh As String, i As Integer

pathh = "D:\Docs\Macro.docx"
Dim pathhi As String
Dim from_text As String, to_text As String
Dim WA As Object, WD As Object
Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WA.Documents.Open (pathh)
WA.Visible = True

  Set regEx = New RegExp
  regEx.Pattern = "Dear[^0-9<>]+)"
  regEx.IgnoreCase = False
  regEx.Global = True

  Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)

  For Each Match In Matches

     ActiveDocument.Range(Match.FirstIndex, Match.FirstIndex + Len(Match.Value)).Bold = True

  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the bracket ")" within the regex, using a back-slash:

```
regex.Pattern = "Dear[^0-9<>]+\)"
```

This is because it has a particular meaning within a regex expression.

I would personally also split the reference to the Word-Range across a few lines:

```
Set rngRange = ActiveDocument.Range
rngRange.Expand Unit:=wdStory
Set Matches = regex.Execute(rngRange.Text)
```

although this isn't necessary.

Comment: This includes the parenthesis. Mine does not. Not sure which one OP wanted.

Comment: @ckuhn203 Because this is Word it is also sometimes tricky to exclude the bracket from formatting.

Comment: How so? You've peeked my interest.

Comment: @ckuhn203 I wasn't expecting a come-back ;). It was just a general comment about Word. Settings such as "automatically select entire word" and "smart paragraph selection" can affect what is actually formatted. In particular, when we select a word, it also selects the space after the word. As I say, just a general comment, I don't have a specific example in mind.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I'm with you now. I thought there was something special about regex in word for a minute. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following text

> Dear aunt sally ) I have gone to school.

Your regex pattern would be `"Dear[^)]+"`

- Find the word Dear
- Match Any character that is not ")"
- Repeat

[regex101 fiddle here](https://regex101.com/r/ewBZxP/1)

This one will include the parenthesis. `Dear[\w\s]+\)`

- Find the word Dear
- Match Any Character or whitespace
- Repeat as needed
- Until a right parenthesis is found

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this - a wildcard Find/Replace in Word will do the job far more efficiently:

```
With WA.ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Text = "Dear[!\)]@\)"
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
  .Replacement.Text = "^&"
  .Format = True
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```